# There are $n$ points inside a $1\times1$ square that can form a convex polygon. Can $3$ of them exist, such that $\mathcal{A}\le\frac{8}{n^2}$?

Tags: combinatorics, area, pigeonhole-principle, inclusion-exclusion

There are $n$ points inside a $1\times1$ square that can form a convex polygon. Can $3$ points of them exist, such that  $\mathcal{A}\le\frac{8}{n^2}$?

where $\mathcal{A}$ area of triangle formed by these three points.

How we can solve this problem using Pigeon-Hole Principle?

Comment: Please write a more informative title

Comment: "Can 3 of them exist"? What about a regular $n$-gon with very small radius centered at center of square? Do you mean is it always possible to find 3 of them such that...

Comment: Yes. Is it always possible to find 3 points such that the area of triangle formed by these three points are less then 8/2^2.

Comment: In that case, it is always possible. It comes down to perimeter of that convex polygon is at most $4$. In general, if you have two convex bodies such that $A \subset B \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, then perimeter of $A \le $ that of $B$.

Comment: But how to get the area?

Comment: If it is a regular polygon, I can get the sides of the polygon is 4/n.
But if it is not regular, how can it always possible to get 2 sides of the polygon is less than 4/n?

Comment: Let $\ell_k$ be $k^{th}$ side length and $\ell_0 = \ell_n$. perimeter $ \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \ell_k \le 4\implies \sum\limits_{k=1}^n (\ell_k + \ell_{k-1}) \le 8\implies \cdots$